Is there a website for creating online quizzes where instead of a text question, you have an image and you choose right or wrong?
Not sure if this is the correct place to ask.
I wanted to create a simple quiz to test my friends (or anyone else) if they can spot if an image is real or ai generated. I was a bit surprised that i didnt find a website where i can easily do that. Seems like no website had everything that i needed.
The quiz should basically work like this:
You press start and it shows you an image. You choose either real or fake and get the next image. It should show you the correct answer right afterwards and the go to the next image. At the end it should show how much you got right.
sporcle does have a lot of quiz type and customization options, though none of them seems to do what i wanted.
triviacreator.com is almost prefect, though the images get degraded. And for that quiz it's important that you have a proper image quality.
A lot of other sites are too basic or are more something for professional usecases, that cost money or have like a quiz mode for your presentation or maybe require an app.
Does anyone know any other quiz/puzzle/test sites that i could try?

Lots of website provide that capability. You should be more specific as I'm sure Sporcle offers that too, except maybe showing the correct one instantly. E.g. should accounts be optional? Sharing through link I assume? Can be public? Any sort of scoring/leaderboards required?
